# Unable to run or install virtual machines - issues with VT

Tags: vmware-workstation

I use VMWare Workstation 6.5 to run VMs on my workstation.  I have recently upgraded by motherboard, chip and RAM and I now get a message about the BOIS VT setting when I try to run an existing VM or install a new VM.  The message is:

> The host is VT-capable, but VT is not enabled.

Then I get other messages about not being able to connect virtual devices (ide1:0).

What should I do to run my VM under Workstation 6.5?  Also, is it safe to change the VT settings for my workstation - I have read about the [Blue Pill](https://serverfault.com/questions/7690/enabling-hardware-virtualisation-bios-anything-to-beware) vulnerability?

My host OS is Win 7 Ultimate, my motherboard is an Asus P8 Z68-V Pro.

Comment: You need to go into your computer's BIOS and enable the VT. Otherwise you will not be able to run VMs well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VMware Workstation you will need hardware-assisted virtualization when running 64-bit virtual machines.

In order to have hardware-assisted virtualization, you will need:

- a processor that supports it
- a board that supports it
- the setting enabled in your BIOS.

You can check if you have it using [Securable](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm).

It is safe to have VT enabled. If not, all the enterprise level virtualization solutions such as VMware EsXI or Microsoft Hyper-V wouldn't require it.